# global cors configuration does not work in spring boot but indivisual @CrossOrigins work

Tags: spring-boot, cors

I have below configs:

```
@Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","HEAD","DELETE","PUT"));
        configuration.setMaxAge(1l);
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

and security config:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                "/auth/**"
            ).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            ;
}
```

but this mix does not work. If I remove `CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()` block and add `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 1)` cors problems will gone!

but I want to register cors globally, what is the problem?

I use spring boot version 2, with spring security and some rest controllers.

(maxAge=1) added because of browser caching that waste a lot of my time!

(if by any chance, browser skips preflight step, why server does not check for origin in real call? that must be checked in server or in client by browser?)

Comment: Check by adding this property.

configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));

Comment: It works! Write it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check by adding this property.

```
configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
```